# Linux select statement with extra options

Tags: linux, bash

I`m busy with writing a script that can download some files from an FTP and i want a select statement to give the directorys in the ftp sub directory. But also to give a option download all this should happen @ $DNAtype at the bottum. Someone any ideas?

My code is:(sorry for the dutch comment)

```
#!/bin/bash/
#16-03-2012
#Sander van der Zeeuw s1040176

#Variabele om de ftp aan te kunnen roepen
var='ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-66/fasta/'
#Hier word de lijst met beschikbare organisme binnengehaald via de functie curl.
# curl is te installeren via de terminal met het command sudo apt-get install curl
lijst=`curl $var | awk '{print $NF}'`

echo "de keuze 0 selecteert alles"

#hier wordt een directory aangemaakt om de files in weg te schrijven
mkdir -p dnaenpep
cd dnaenpep



#Hier wordt een keuze menu gecreeerd om het juiste organisme te kiezen.
select specie in $lijst
do
    break
done
echo "Uw keuze is:" $specie


#Hier wordt de keuze "0" ingebouwd. Zodat alle genomen gedownload worden.
if [ "$specie" == "" ]
then
    for i in $lijst
    do
        namen=$(curl $var$i/dna/ | awk '{print($NF)}')
        for files in $namen; do curl $var$i/dna/$files -o $files
                    curl $var$i/pep/$files -o $files
        done 
    done
fi

echo "de keuze 0 selecteert alles"

#Wanneer de loop niet uitgevoerd wordt, zal via nog een select statement de gekozen worden #welk DNA je van de ftp wil downloaden. 
lijst2=`curl $var$specie/ | awk '{print $9}'`
echo $lijst2

select dnatype in $lijst2
do
    break
done
echo "uw keuze is:" $dnatype

if [$dnatype == ""]
then
    for i in $dnatype
    do
        wget -O DNAtype "$var$specie/dna/"
        wget -O DNAtype "$var$specie/pep/"
    done
fi

#Hier worden de files die in $dnatype gemaakt worden gedownload.
wget -O DNAtype "$var$specie/$dnatype/"

cat DNAtype | egrep "=" | tr '"' '\n' | sort | grep ^"ftp" |grep gz > Downlist.txt
wget -c -i  Downlist.txt

exit
```

Comment: This script has too many issues. The most immediate `select` issue is the word-splitting for iteration over `$lijst`, but there are many other [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and syntax problems that will cause this to this fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement should use an array and you can add additional items to the array or add them after the array name in the `select` statement.

```
lijst2=($(curl "$var$specie/" | awk '{print $9}')
lijst2+=("Another option" "Additional option" "Download all")
echo "${lijst2[@]}"

select dnatype in "${lijst2[@]}"
do
    break
done
echo "uw keuze is: $dnatype"
```

or

```
lijst2=($(curl "$var$specie/" | awk '{print $9}')
echo "${lijst2[@]}"

select dnatype in "${lijst2[@]}" "Another option" "Additional option" "Download all"

do
    break
done
echo "uw keuze is: $dnatype"
```

Which you choose depends on whether you want the added options in the array.

To download all, just iterate over the array (so you'll probably want to use the second version so you don't have to skip over "Download all", for example, since it's not a filename.

Additional notes:

Use `$()` instead of backticks for command substitution.

This statement `if [$dnatype == ""]` needs spaces: `if [ $dnatype == "" ]`.

Quote all your variables when they are expanded. You have done this in some places, but not others.

Your long pipeline near the end can almost certainly be simplified. Without seeing example data I could only guess how.

Comment: Thanks for the help one more question how can i add an option that downloads lets say the directory pep and dna??

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Where I have "Another option" in my examples, just put "Download pep and dna". After the `select` block test to see if `$dnatype` contains that string and if so, do the appropriate `curl` command(s).

Comment: alright, i understand. But the curl command cant split the links in 2 files 1 think, because 1 dir is pep and 1 dir is dna?